# PHP foreach with more condition

Tags: php

Is it possible to set `foreach` function more than 2 condition. Example like below:

```
$stat_cps = $_POST['stat_cp'];
$acc_idss = $_POST['acc_ids'];

$string = 'NG';
foreach ($stat_cps as $url)
{
     if(strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE)
     {
          echo "One of the field is NG";
          return true;
     }
}

echo "All field is OK";
```

What I want is:
if `$stat_cps` or `$acc_idss` contains NG then `echo "One of the field is NG";`

On the above code, it's only working for `$stat_cps`

*stat_cps and acc_idss is from radio button form.

Anyone can give the suggestion?

Comment: array_merge to merge both your arrays into 1?

Comment: Any example @TommyBs ?

Comment: $newarray= array_merge($stat_cps, $acc_idss); now foreach on $newarray

Comment: what value come this varibales `$stat_cps ` and `$acc_idss` ?

Comment: show sample values ?

Comment: Hi @VadivelS $stat_cps and $acc_idss got from radio button form submit

Comment: `$stat_cps` and `$acc_idss` two varibales values come in single ?  and show sample values

Comment: No, multiple values for each

Comment: how will be arrays come from radio button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_merge to combine both your arrays:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$stat_cps = $_POST['stat_cp'];
$acc_idss = $_POST['acc_ids'];
$merged = array_merge($stat_cps,$acc_idss);
$string = 'NG';
foreach ($merged as $url)
{
     if(strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE)
     {
          echo "One of the field is NG";
          return true;
     }
}
```

This will remove duplicate string keys but it doesn't look like that should be an issue here if you just want one match

From you comment try doing

```
 $stat_cps = $_POST['stat_cp'];
$acc_idss = $_POST['acc_ids'];
$merged = array_merge($stat_cps,$acc_idss);
$match = false;
$string = 'NG';
foreach ($merged as $url)
{
     if(strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE)
     {
          $match =  true;
     }
}

if($match){
       echo "One of the field is NG";
}else{
      echo "Everything is OK";
}
```

Comment: Hi... when I put echo "All field is OK"; outside foreach it always give result OK even though one of the field contains NG.

Comment: If it's outside the foreach then it will always display regardless as it's not applied to that logic

Comment: From your comment if you just want a match (your return true is doing nothing) try using the second code example that sets a flag based on the existence (called $match)

Comment: How about if I have database query there? Actually what I want is when the 2 string (with multiple values from radio button) have NG status, then it  will update the database table NG, but if All OK then OK

Comment: Then add your mysql query to the if($match){} statement where it echoes "One of the field is NG" I'm sorry and I don't want to seem rude but if you're struggling to write a MySQL query that's a separate question. I'm not going to write everything for you as you should make an attempt yourself otherwise it just feels like you're getting someone else to do your work.

Answer (score 2):

"One-line" solution with `array_merge`, `implode` and `strpos` functions:

```
...
$hasNg = strpos("NG", implode(",", array_merge($stat_cps,$acc_idss)));
...

// check for 'NG' occurance
echo ($hasNg !== false)? "One of the field is NG" : "string 'NG' doesn't exists within passed data";
```

Comment: nice concise solution, that's what I like about this site, you always see things you didn't think of it combining various features of a language

Answer (score 0):

```
$stat_cps = $_POST['stat_cp'];
$acc_idss = $_POST['acc_ids'];

$process=0;
$string = 'NG';
foreach ($stat_cps as $url)
{
     if(strpos($string, $url) !== FALSE)
     {
          $process=1;
     }
}
foreach ($acc_idss as $url2)
{
     if(strpos($string, $url2) !== FALSE)
     {
          $process=1;
     }
}
if($process==1){
  echo "One of the field is NG";
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @HiDayurie Dave : check this

Comment: Hi, actually in that condition I have database query to save the field. If using 2 foreach like your code I think I need to have 2 database query. Is it right?

Comment: no need to take 2 database query.U can use single query

Comment: Example, if NG then save the query to be NG, if OK then save the query to be OK.

Comment: u can also set condition in one query.No need to perform 2 queries.

Comment: U can also use ternary op. return ($process== 1) ? 'NG' : 'Ok'; and pass result into query

Answer (score 0):

```
#header  user in_array()
    $stat_cps = $_POST['stat_cp'];
    $acc_idss = $_POST['acc_ids'];

    $string = 'NG';
    foreach ($stat_cps as $url)
    {
         if(in_array($string, $url) !== FALSE)
         {
              echo "One of the field is NG";
              return true;
         }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the initial problem "... more than 2 condition"